# Lumen/Laravel many-to-many (fetch data in the middle)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, lumen

I am testing out Lumen here and have a question regarding many-to-many relationship.

I've read the documentation, but I've either overlooked the answer or I might be dumber then I think. Also have to add that I am pretty new to the MVC pattern.

So I have an example here where we can have many permissions, many users and each user can have many permissions.

I have 3 database tables:

```
-------------------------------------
| users | id | firstname | lastname |
-------------------------------------
```

---

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| permissions_users | id | permission_id | user_id | from | to |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
----------------------------------
| permissions | id | name | desc |
----------------------------------
```

And for now I've created 2 models:

**User:**

```
public function permissions(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'permissions_users', 'user_id', 'permission_id');
}
```

**Permission:**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'permissions_users', 'permission_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Now my question is, what if I want to fetch the "from" and "to" dates in the permissions_users table, what do I do?

Do I create a model called PermissionUser "between" that act as a middleman between User and Permission or is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define these attributes also in select on relation. I think this will work for you.

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'permissions_users', 'user_id', 'permission_id')->select(['from', 'to']);
}
```

You might need to add permission columns too in select else it might show only from and to in your relation object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Composer is super slow at the moment, but I'll try your suggestion as soon as I am up and running and vote your answer as correct if it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'permissions_users', 'user_id', 'permission_id')
        ->withPivot('from', 'to');
}

foreach($user->permissions as $permission){
    $permission->pivot->from;
    $permission->pivot->to;
}
```